# How to indent both sides of a bordered box without changing text

Tags: html, css

I have this bordered box:

```css
.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px ridge white;
  border: 2px ridge rgb(50, 50, 50);
  border-radius: 1em;
  /*8px*/
  padding-left: 15%;
  padding-right: 15%;
  padding-top: 5%;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">Hello World!</div>
```

If I change width to a smaller percentage (e.g. width: 90%), the right edge moves left, but the left edge does not move, and the text margins also move in.  I want both edges to move -- the left edge should move right by the same amount as the right edge moves left -- and I don't want the text margins within the boxes to move at all.

How can I do what I described with a bordered box?

Comment: margin: 0 auto?

Comment: Thanks, but margin: 0 auto does not do it.

Comment: Did you try `text-align: center`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think I understood you well but here are two solutions for you.

**Solution 1:**

You can use `margin` but you'll **have** to specify a width.

```css
.box {
  width: 50%; /** setting a width is required **/
  margin: auto;
  border: 2px ridge rgb(50, 50, 50);
  border-radius: 1em;
  padding-left: 15%;
  padding-right: 15%;
  padding-top: 5%;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">Hello World!</div>
```

**Solution 2:**

You can use `transform` property by the help of `translate3d` function. You don't have to specify a width. For example, you can declare the `display` as `inline-block` to make the width as the content's original width.

> You can just use `translateX` function instead of `translate3d` and it should work the same way. Also, setting a `width` will give the same results.

```css
.box {
  /** no width is specified but you can set one **/
  display: inline-block; /** the width now equals the content width **/
  position: relative; /** required to use left property **/
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
  border: 2px ridge rgb(50, 50, 50);
  border-radius: 1em;
  padding-left: 15%;
  padding-right: 15%;
  padding-top: 5%;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">Hello World!</div>
```

Hope I pushed you further.

Comment: That helps.  Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you shrink width by 10% just add margin-left:5%; better than that is the following:

```
.box {
     position:absolute;
     width: 90%;
     left:50%; 
     margin-left:-45%; /*this must be always 1/2 of the width and negative*/ 
     height: 100%; 
     padding: 10px; 
     border: 2px ridge white; 
     border: 2px ridge rgb(50, 50, 50);
     border-radius: 1em; 
    /*8px*/ padding-left: 15%; 
    padding-right: 15%; 
    padding-top: 5%; 
    padding-bottom: 5%; 
 }
```

This way the div will be always centered relatively to its parent element. Hope it helps.

Comment: I thought we should not use negative margins.  What are your thoughts on that?

Comment: There's no reason not to use a negative margin. They work fine across the board. Just make sure to test different sizes/responsive layouts to make sure it doesn't have an unexpected impact.

Answer (score 0):

I try set `margin: 0 auto;` to `.box` class as lucifer63 said and it worked for equals external borders. And how you do not want the text margins inside the box do not move, set fix padding how `padding: 32px`. You can also use 
`display: flex; align-itens: center; justify-content: flex-start;` and put a height to .box